# Which, if any, recent Windows updates should I uninstall to revivify Silverlight or rectify other problems?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, silverlight

All of a sudden, a large asp.net project stopped working, without any code changes relevant to the problem. As we are using Visual Studio 2010 here at work, I uninstalled the Update for Visual Studio 2012 (KB2781514), which perhaps had been installed because I installed a version of Visual Web Developer Express. Anyway, whether or not uninstalling that update fixed the problem, I don't know, because it is perhaps *prior* to the spot where a permissions/authentication error was occurring in the project that I now see this in our Silverlight report viewer page:

[image]

As the code had not changed from "working fine" to "no longer working" (the exact same code works on another machine, one that is not shut down each night and thus does not have all the updates that I have on my machine), we determined it was perhaps some updates to the computer that were gumming up the works.

In Windows 7, I can see installed updates via All Programs | Windows Updates | View Update History | Installed Updates, and found these updates in the window (no pun intended) between when the project was last observed working and when it busted down around O'Connally Corners (gratuitous Doobies reference):

**6/18:**

*.NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack (1):
KB2504637*

**6/19:**

*Windows Management Framework 3.0:
KB2506143
Update for Visual Studio:
KB2781514 - uninstalled 6/21, but still get Silverlight err msg (see SilverlightErrMsg.png)*

**6/20:**

*Update for Windows:
KB2823180
KB2809215
KB2809900
Security Update for .NET Framework 4.5:
KB2737083
KB2742613
Update for MS .NET Framework 4.5:
KB2750147
KB2805221
KB2805226*

I don't want to go on a "wild goose chase" uninstalling everything an update at a time, rebooting, retesting, etc. (if I can help it).

Is anybody aware of any of these updates causing a problem, or have an educated intuition on which one[s] could be the culprit[s]?

### UPDATE

I reinstalled the Silverlight SDK, and it moved the error from one place to another, and to a different error. Now it's:

*System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147286790
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'TLDCommonLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4ced62d0f7a74a89' or one of its dependencies. An API call exited abnormally. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800300FA (STG_E_ABNORMALAPIEXIT))
  Source=PollerDataImportServiceLib
  FileName=TLDCommonLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4ced62d0f7a74a89
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = CCR\u9867duckbilledPlatypus*

Comment: Even though I provided an answer, I believe this question is off-topic for Programmers.  I believe it is more appropriate on stack overflow.  Currently there are 3 off-topic close votes, so this question is likely going to be migrated to SO.

Comment: Interesting; I normally post on SO, but thought this was more appropriate here, as it is not a programming question per se; that is to say, this problem can't be rectified by my writing code. It's a configuration or install/uninstall issue, ISTM.

Comment: I would put this in the category of "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" which falls in the SO camp.  Not a great categorization there, but also not a big deal.  It's not hideously off-topic for P.SE as there aren't any down votes.  Programmers is more about conceptual and whiteboard design type questions.  For the most part, the [help on-topic section](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does a decent job outlining the site.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems in the past with updates to Windows and / or VS breaking the Silverlight SDK.

Usually, reinstalling the Silverlight SDK will resolve this.  Sometimes I have had to reinstall Silverlight and the SDK.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263514/visual-studio-2010-build-error-exception-from-hresult-0x800300fa-stg-e-abnor) on SO has a similar issue regarding that new exception you are seeing. The answer revolves around correcting user permissions.

Comment: Thanks for that link; I won't get a chance to czech it out until Monday, though...

Comment: Now going 'round in circles at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282705/why-did-reinstalling-silverlight-break-my-import-configuration