# Visual Studio 2022 error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800300FA (STG_E_ABNORMALAPIEXIT)

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an ASP.Net Web forms project in Visual Studio 2022. When I try to build it, an error message appears.

> An API call exited abnormally. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800300FA (STG_E_ABNORMALAPIEXIT))

This error also appears when I try to exit Visual Studio. I have to kill the process to proceed.

The same project works fine in Visual Studio 2019.

Any idea where to start? The error message is not very insightful.

I already tried setting the rights on the framework Temporary ASP.NET Files folder. I didn't help.

The issue is also only with one project - other projects work fine.

Is there a way I can get a Visual Studio log. Any ideal where this is stored for Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2010 Build Error - Exception from HRESULT: 0x800300FA (STG\_E\_ABNORMALAPIEXIT))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263514/visual-studio-2010-build-error-exception-from-hresult-0x800300fa-stg-e-abnor)

Comment: No, I already tried that.

Answer (score 16):

Try deleting the .vs folder at the root of your project that fixed it for me

Comment: Cannot delete it, says "the action cannot be completed because the folder is open in servicehub.indexingservice.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Vs22 is now x64 bits, and is the first such version to be so.
This also means we see a lot more issues and errors in regards to running your application as any CPU as opposed to forcing the project bit size.
It's not clear if you always forced the bit size, or perhaps your project say references unmanaged code that's say x32 bits.

So I would force and change the project to run as x32 bits if that was the settings in the past.
And in fact any CPU used to result in your application (f5) to run as x32 bits, now that default any CPU setting will result in a x64 but running and debug session.

You don't mention your current project settings, but I would try x32 bits, especially if you used any CPU in the past.

Comment: I tried that. I can only set it to x32 for a class library - with no effect to the result.

Comment: Hum, I assume this project is not just a class library. In configuration manager you have to make a new one - create as x32. At that point rebuild and see if it compiles, and then can run

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue after recent Visual Studio 2022 update. Was not able to build, run, publish solution at all. To resolve it I just pushed all my changes into repo and cloned it to new folder.

Have no idea what was a root cause, but it helped...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the issue through a combination of the following:

- Closed Visual Studio
- Removed `**/bin/**` `**/obj/**`
- Updated Visual Studio to the latest version
- Removed the component cache: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1x.0\ComponentModelCache`
- Removed all temporary files in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`

Those locations are also mentioned on the [internets](https://dotnetrevisited.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache.html), but I didn't touch them:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation`
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon`