# unable to start debugging the startup project could not be launched an API code exited abnormally in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#

an api call exited abnormally. (exception from hresult: 0x800300fa (stg_e_abnormalapiexit)) in visual studio, for this I put the entire project into c://User//Source//Repo, but still not get solution, please help anyone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2022 error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800300FA (STG\_E\_ABNORMALAPIEXIT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418668/visual-studio-2022-error-exception-from-hresult-0x800300fa-stg-e-abnormalapie)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.